# How can I prevent overwriting user data in Firebase when multiple users register with my registration form?

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase

I'm building a registration form with HTML, JS, and Firebase that adds each new user to their own Auth. However, I'm encountering a problem when it comes to adding user data to the database. Specifically, while my code correctly loads a user's information to my Firebase database and creates their Auth when I register Person1 with email1, when I try to register Person2 with email2, their data overwrites Person1's data.

How can I modify my code to prevent overwriting user data when multiple users register with my registration form and instead allow for registering multiple users to their own user in the database?

Here's my app.js code for reference:

```
// Firebase imports and config...

// HTML objects
const firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
const lastname = document.getElementById("lastname");
const email = document.getElementById("Email");
const passwords = document.getElementById("password");
const copassword = document.getElementById("copassword");

// Queried HTML objects
const firstname_qry = document.querySelector("#firstname");
const lastname_qry = document.querySelector("#lastname");
const email_qry = document.querySelector("#Email");
const passwords_qry = document.querySelector("#password");
const copassword_qry = document.querySelector("#copassword");
const registroBoton_qry = document.querySelector("#insert")

// Function for storing data
window.signup = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const obj = {
        firstname: firstname.value,
        lastname: lastname.value,
        email: email.value,
        passwords: passwords.value,
        copassword: copassword.value,
    }
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, obj.email, obj.passwords)
        .then(function (success) {
            alert("Auth Succesfull");
            window.location.href = "loginTrainMate.html";
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            alert("Error" + err);
        })

    // Adding athlete user information to the database
    // This is where the issue lies!
    set(ref(database, `Athletes/${obj.email}`), {
        firstname: obj.firstname,
        lastname: obj.lastname,
        email: obj.email,
        passwords: obj.passwords,
        copassword: obj.copassword,
    })
        .then(function (success) {
            alert("Signup succesful");
            window.location.href = "loginTrainMate.html";
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            alert("Error" + err);
        })
    console.log(obj)
};

// Click event
registroBoton_qry.addEventListener('click', addAthlete);
```